# Disable touchableopacity until validation is true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to disable my submit button until email and password matches my validation parameters, I am able to do this for one input field, however, I cannot seem to wrap my head around being able to do same for more that one textinput, everything I have tried have not worked as I even tried doing it in componentDidMount. Below is a rough sample code of what I have at the moment.

```
        class Login extends Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              showpass: true,
              email: '',
              password: '',
              validEmail: true,
              validPassword: true,
              disabled: true,
            };
          }

          onChangeEmail(email) {
            const emailCheckRegex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
            this.setState({ email });

            if (emailCheckRegex.test(email)) {
              console.log('Email is Correct');
              this.setState({
                validEmail: true, disabled: false,
              });
            } else if (!emailCheckRegex.test(email)) {
              console.log('Email is not Correct');
              this.setState({
                validEmail: false, disabled: true,
              });
            }
          }

          onChangePassword(password) {
            this.setState({ password });
              if (password.length > 5) {
                //Password has to be at least 5 characters long
                this.setState({
                  validPassword: true,
                });
              } else if (password.length <= 5) {
                this.setState({
                  validPassword: false,
                });
              }
          }



          render() {
            const { showpass, email, password, validEmail, validPassword, disabled } = this.state;
            const opacityStyle = disabled ? 0.2 : 1;

            return (
            <View style={styles.inputWrapper}>
              <Text style={styles.loginTextStyle}>Email</Text>
              <View style={validEmail ? styles.inputCon : styles.inputConError}>
                <TextInput
                  placeholderTextColor='#343845'
                  style={styles.inputField}
                  onChangeText={this.onChangeEmail.bind(this)}
                  value={email}
                  keyboardType='email-address'
                  autoCorrect={false}
                  // placeholder={placeholder}
                  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                />
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.inputWrapper}>
              <Text style={styles.loginTextStyle}>Password</Text>
              <View style={validPassword ? styles.inputCon : styles.inputConError}>
                <TextInput
                  placeholderTextColor='#343845'
                  style={styles.inputField}
                  onChangeText={this.onChangePassword.bind(this)}
                  value={password}
                  keyboardType='email-address'
                  autoCorrect={false}
                  // placeholder={placeholder}
                  secureTextEntry={showpass}
                  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                  returnKeyType='done'
                />
              </View>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={[{ opacity: opacityStyle }, styles.btnStyle]}
                disabled={disabled}
              >
                <Text style={styles.loginStyle}>Login</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: disabled is set to true and you are not updating it, how are you achieving it for one ?

Comment: I have updated the code above

Answer (score 0):

```
 disabled={this.state.email === '' || this.state.password === ''}
```

is that what you mean?

Comment: yeah, but not when it is empty, but when it does not contain an email and a password of 5 characters or more

Comment: its not still working, the button remains disabled. Can you help in looking at it again?

Answer (score 0):

You have validEmail and validPassword in state, it's default value should be false as

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          showpass: true,
          email: '',
          password: '',
          validEmail: false,
          validPassword: false,
        };
      }
```

then you can use these to keep the submit disable until both are validated as

```
// ...
<TouchableOpacity
   style={[{ opacity: opacityStyle }, styles.btnStyle]}
   disabled={!this.state.validEmail || !this.state.validPassword}
>
// remaining code
```

You don't need disabled in state

Hope it helps

Comment: its not still working, the button remains disabled. Can you help in looking at it again?

Comment: are you able to type in your TextInput ?

Comment: yes I can type into my textinput, and also i am working with react native, I dont think i can make a sandbox snippet using that.

Comment: your password length should be six to make the button enable

Comment: can you validate, what's the value of this.state.validEmail and this.state.validPassword when you  type valid values?

Comment: i can validate the textinput, and validEmail and password are just to indicate to the user that the right values haven't been inputted into those fields by changing the border color to red

Comment: just console.log validEmail and validPassword inside render

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple function to validate your inputs, just have one function for handling input changes and one for validation.

```
disabled: false, // set disable to false by default

handleInput = (name, value) => {
  this.setState(
    {
      [name]: value,
    },
    this.validateInput
  );
};

validateInput = () => {
  const emailCheckRegex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  const validEmail = emailCheckRegex.test(this.state.email);
  const validPassword =
    (this.state.password && this.state.password.length > 5) || false;

  this.setState({
    validEmail: validEmail,
    disabled: (validEmail && validPassword) || false,
    validPassword: validPassword,
  });
};

const opacityStyle = disabled ? 1 : 0.2; // change opacity logic

<TouchableOpacity
  style={[{ opacity: opacityStyle }, styles.btnStyle]}
  disabled={!disabled}> {/* change here as well */}
  <Text style={styles.loginStyle}>Login</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

[DEMO](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/inputvalidation)